# I created an ER Diagram for a room rental, and i have some questions

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

[LINK TO ER DIAGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZj84.png) 
[image: ER Diagram]

The owner of this room rents the room to tourist and people who visit the area for a couple of days and need a place to spend a couple of days. Each guest needs to make a reservation and there's only one room available. 
So I came up with this entity relationship diagram indicating all entities and relationships.

Questions
I'm wondering if the booking entity requires two foreign keys?
Also, Is overall design of the ER Diagram correct to an acceptable level including keys and attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Your model has a few issues:

- Each owner can own only one room.  In the real world, owners could own many rooms.  Even if, for now, you want a bijective relationship, I suggest you take that relationship out of the Owner table in case you want to change it later.
- Each room has only one client ever.  If the real world, rooms could house different clients during different bookings.  Remove the relationship with the client from the Room table.
- Each client has only one booking ever.  In the real world, clients can have different bookings over time.  Remove the relationship with booking from the Client table.
- Booking_ID sounds like a surrogate key for bookings.  Why is the client part of the primary key?  I think it should be a non-prime attribute, and indicate that it will be in a foreign key constraint as already depicted on the diagram.
- Booking has a foreign key constraint on Room_ID, but your diagram doesn't depict it.
- Payment_ID in the Payment table is in a foreign key constraint, but it sounds like a surrogate key for that table.  I think Payment_ID in the Booking table as well as Booking_ID in the Payment should be the ones constrained.
- What's the purpose of the Payment table?  It looks redundant, even if it isn't you can move those functional dependencies into the Bookings table, and then the Payment_ID can be eliminated.
- If you remove the Payment_ID from the Booking table, you'll still have two keys which are in a foreign key constraint.